# Adding curlpp library with CLion cmake to C++ project

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, clion, curlpp

Im using CLion with cmake system building on Windows 10. I want to add this curlpp https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp for http request. I download lib from GitHub and put into project folder. Next I add this to my CMake lists:

```
add_subdirectory(curlpp-master)
```

Cmake throw unfortunately error:

```
Error:Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

After that I decided to add original C curl https://github.com/curl/curl , with the same way that curlpp. So now this looks like that:

```
add_subdirectory(curl-7.47.1)
add_subdirectory(curlpp-master)
```

But yet I see the same error with not finding curl library. How can I add properly curlpp?

Comment: Does this command work for you on windows cmd? `curl-config --libs`